# Joomla module and variables within functions

Tags: php, function, joomla

I have created a module in Joomla and all is working fine, but when I put a function in and try and access a variable it does not work, but if I echo it outside the function it is ok

```
$item_img = $params->get('item_img','modules/mod_k2_mobile/images/item_icon.gif');

// not working
function GetIMG(){
    global $item_img;
    echo "item".$item_img;
}
GetIMG();

// working
echo "item".$item_img;
```

why?

Comment: Didn't you already get he answer here: 
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=642&t=676539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you not to use any global variables as long as you can avoid it. Can't you change your function declaration to something like "GetIMG( $item_img )"?
If you still want to use a global variable, this should work:

```
**global $item_img;**

$item_img = $params->get('item_img','modules/mod_k2_mobile/images/item_icon.gif');

// not working
function GetIMG(){
    global $item_img;
    echo "item".$item_img;
}
GetIMG();

// working
echo "item".$item_img;
```

I hope it helps!